# Visualized data analysis for Django (Postgres) data

Tags: python, django, postgresql, analysis

I'm writing a Django app (that uses Postgres 8.4 as the backend) that aggregates a large volume of data (154 GB, 150 Tables).  I'd like to know if there are any existing Python modules or frameworks that support analysis across multiple tables and columns.

For example:

- Table 1 has columns A, B, C
- Table 2 has columns A, D
- Table 3 has columns F, G, H, I

I'd like to see how B relates/corresponds to D - plotting B vs D in 2 axes or other forms.  It would be nice if I could feed it a list of dimensions and it could compare any one to another.

Answer (score 1):

Prewarning: All 3 of the db-based graphing libraries I worked with that do what you want use NOT Postgres (...and I only liked 2 of them anyway...).

If you're still early in development you may want to consider [graphite](http://graphite.wikidot.com/). It does have great graphing functionality and is very clean to work with as well is written in python.

If you want something with more of a kick, [OpenTSDB](http://opentsdb.net/).

The easiest way to use either of these would be to write a shellscript/scraper to query your tables and spit it back to your graphite/opentsdb instance. If you're looking to map directly from your db, you might have better luck recycling graphite's code.

Answer (score 1):

You are going to have to write custom SQL code, and how you plugin that data into an app or a graphing monitoring system depends on you.

+1 for graphite, and with collectd+graphite plugin and a [postgresql plugin](http://collectd.org/wiki/index.php/Plugin:PostgreSQL) it's easy to get postgresql data into graphite.

The things you want to monitor are related to a specific database AND probably to your use case, afaik there is nothing in pythonland that will help you with the SQL.

For those who aren't postgresql gurus there is an excellent [book](http://www.packtpub.com/postgresql-9-admin-cookbook/book) with a whole bunch of examples of monitoring/admin queries.

[image]

Personally I wouldn't use django itself for these operations, but they can be done easily using rawsql and then you can just define some models to hold the data, and use your visualization tool of choice to display the data.